# How to adjust animation linked to a hover event?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, hover, css-animations

I have a header composed of navigation links to other websites, some of these links are shown through drop-down menus. With the event hover I have added an animation and style to see what you are on at every moment and that, in case of a drop-down, shows you all the options. The thing is that once the dropdown has been shown I have added the same style and animation to the internal links as to the main ones, but in the case of the animation I always have the underline in the same place instead of just below each link. Thanks in advance for your time and help. I leave you a link with an example as I have it now working with the described behavior

https://codepen.io/carlosurra/pen/YzqXjdP

my template

```
<div id="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light header">
                 
                  
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav menu">
                      
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">PERSONAL INFO</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item" @mouseover="animalList = true" @mouseleave="animalList = false" >
                        <a class="nav-link menu-link-toggle" >PERSONAL FORM</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="animalList">
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>DATA</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>FORM DATA</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >AUTOCOMPLETE</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item" @mouseover="serviceList = true" @mouseleave="serviceList = false">
                        <a class='nav-link menu-link menu-link-toggle' >SERVICES</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="serviceList">
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >LA CRÉMATION PRIVÉE</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >PERSONAL S</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>COMPANY S</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >FULL S INFO</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link ">SHOP</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item active">
                        <router-link class="nav-link" to="/devis">PRICES</router-link>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item" @mouseover="contactList = true" @mouseleave="contactList = false">
                        <a class='menu-link nav-link menu-link-toggle' >CONTACT</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="contactList">
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>MAIL</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >PHONE</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li> 
                    </ul>
                  </div>
              </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my css

```
html, body {
  background:  #009050;
}


.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.menu-link-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 1.25em 0.5em 0.75em;
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
}

.dropdown-menu-item {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.head {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}



.nav-item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 35%;
  background: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}

.nav-item:hover:before,
.nav-item:focus:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);

}

.dropdown-menu-link:before {
    content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  background: #D53865;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;  
}

.dropdown-menu-link:hover:before,
.dropdown-menu-link:focus:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


.added {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please add this to your code**

```
.dropdown-menu-link {
   padding-bottom:3px;
   position:relative;
}
.dropdown-menu-item {
   position:relative;
}
```

**Change the code** `bottom:30%;` to `bottom: 0px;`

```
.dropdown-menu-link:before {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Please check this codepen :
https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/LYNpyEx

Comment: Check the answer @javascript110899

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to `.dropdown-menu-item` and set a correct position to bottom of `.dropdown-menu-item:before`, let's say to 0px;

Or if you want to be relative to the link set `position: relative` to `.dropdown-menu-link`.